# Change Adaptive Cards in Botframework with jQuery CSS

Tags: jquery, css, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am using the MS BotFramework with C# to render an Adaptive Card that looks like this:

[image: Adaptive card image]

When the user clicks on one of the stars the number is sent back to the bot.
This is working fine.
But we also want to update the UI with jQuery and CSS that the user get visual feedback that the selection was successful.
We are using the Webchat V3 with DirectLine.

It seems like the Webchat is blocking the jQuery and CSS code.
Is there any way to get this working?

I think the Botframework HostConfig allows custom styling by default.

Comment: I understand you want the Adaptive Card to change when a button is clicked. This isn't an unusual goal, but most channels don't allow modification of past messages. Of course, however, when you're using DirectLine you get to make your own client so you can have it do whatever you want. WebChat is an example of such a client, and if it isn't working the way you want then you can edit it as you please. It is open source after all. But it your case, the easiest way of giving feedback is to just send a new message saying the feedback was submitted successfully. That would work in any channel.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are right. But our customer would prefer an Amazon like star rating. I looked into the Webchat React code but I think it is not so easy to change and when we make changes there we have problems with the updates in the future.

Comment: Do you mean problems with WebChat updates?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We decided to implement a workaround. After receiving the result of the star Rating the bot is sending the Rating back via the DirectChannel and then a JS function is updating the UI. This was the best solution for us because we didn't change the webchat code itself.

Comment: I'd like to see the JS function etc. if you don't mind posting some of your code